# Sign-in with google user in an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-app-engine

I read [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) in order to connect my AngularJS app with google sign-in. I added the google button as follows (just copy-pasting the tutorial):

In the head I added the meta tag:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
```

And then added the button itself:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

At first I just copied the `onSignIn` method (that's just a generic handler so I'm not copying it to the question) from the tutorial and put it in a `<script>...</script>` tag and it worked. I now want to put this method in an Angular controller. So I created a controller as follows:

```
app.controller('GoogleCtrl', function() {
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
   }
}
```

And wrapped the button with a div:

```
<div ng-controller="GoogleCtrl">
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
</div>
```

My code doesn't get to the `onSignIn` method now and I'm trying to figure out what can I do.

Comment: In the tutorial `onSignIn` is a function on window object while the controller version is just named function inside controller, you might add listener to window in your controller

Comment: @maurycy - Thanks! I have to admit, I'm not very proficient in JS and I'm not really sure I understand your comment or how to use it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you follow the instructions, what you will end up with is `window. onSignIn` - try to run it in your browser JS console, now to have the same behaviour you will need to crate that function from your controller.

```
app.controller('GoogleCtrl', function() {
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
   }
  window.onSignIn = onSignIn;
}
```

Remember that code executed by 3rd party like `onSignIn` will need to call `$scope.$digest`, so angular is aware of model changes.

Comment: Thanks! Now I got you. And thanks for mentioning the need to call $digest. This probably saved me a half-day's work to figure out why things aren't updated on the screen :)

Comment: That is a problem that happens way too often so to be on safe side better do the heads-up

Comment: I have the same problem and I applied the same sollution, but now I get googleUser.getAuthResponse is not defined. Can you share the listener function as well?

Comment: @maurycy so simple, yet I could not figure out why it was not working. Works perfect. Thank you for your wisdom :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, it seems like you might have to add listener for your function. To keep things simple, you can easily integrate google login in your app with this plugin. https://github.com/sahat/satellizer

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll check this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your version of AngularJS, but it shouldn't matter. I solved this for AngularJS 1.x as follows:

```js
allControllers.controller('authenticateController', ['$rootScope', $scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  // do whatever you're doing on this page...
  // initialize The GoogleAuth API explicitly
  // The load an init below can be placed in your app.js in you feel like you want to implement the whole lifecycle Google provides.
  gapi.load('auth2', function() { // Loads the auth2 component of gapi
    gapi.auth2.init({ // initialize the auth2 using your credentials
      client_id: $GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID
    }).then(function onInit() { // on complete of init
      gapi.signin2.render("g-signin2", { // render the HTML button on the screen providing the ID of the element (g-signin2)
        onsuccess: function(googleUser) { // This executes when a user successfully authorizes you to their data by clicking the button and selecting their account.
          var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
          console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
          console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
          console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
          console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
          // Do whatever you need to do to authenticate on your site.
        }
      });
    });
  });
}]);
```

```html
// In your index.html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

// In your login fragment
<div id="g-signin2" style="width: 200px; margin: 20px auto 20px auto;"></div>
```