# Add Google Sign-In to Your Web using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-signin

I have tried a demo and its working but when I try in angular it's not perfectly working. and **the problem is a function, it's not working**.

sign in button

```
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn()" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

added dependency and create clientID

```
  <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="******644722-rv6i1sh8437nc82o8egufkui0424k1qg.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

function  called

```
    $scope.onSignIn=function(googleUser){
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());  
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

  };
```

Comment: As per your code, the onSignIn function should get parameter. You should pass param when you call in view.

Comment: @AkashGadhiya I pass parameter but same error and tx for the response

Comment: What type of problem are you facing? Please add in the description. It will more helpful.

Comment: when I click to sign in button and after login successfully functions called. but function not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742428/sign-in-with-google-user-in-an-angularjs-app)